# Add whiskers (horizontal lines) to multiple boxplots

Tags: r, lines, boxplot

I need to add whisker (or horizontal lines) to my multiple box-plots.

You can find my dataset here: [link to data is broken...](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70196097/dataset.txt)

In other words, I am plotting three variables (Mat, Ita, and Log) divided by Gender (F and M), in order to compare their box plots. I need to add an horizontal line at the end of both vertical lines in each box plot.

I am using ggplot2 package and the code I am using so far is (this code allows me to create the box plots as I need them, I only need to add the horizontal lines):

```
ggplot(newdata,aes(x=variable,y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Gender)) + 
  xlab("Subject") + 
  ylab("Quiz score") + 
  ggtitle("Boxplots for quiz score and gender") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("pink","lightblue"),labels=c("Female","Male")) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar')`

I provide an example:

```
bp <- ggplot(iris, aes(factor(Species), Sepal.Width, fill = Species))
bp + geom_boxplot() + stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar')
```

Result:

[image]